# Unexpected Key 1-10 in params with translateText

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

So I'm just running a function to translate text with AWS Translate. Here is my params and the call to the function:

```js
const translate = new AWS.Translate({ apiVersion: '2017-07-01' });

const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

const params = {
  "TableName": "sites",
  "Item": {
    SourceLanguageCode: 'auto', /* required */
    TargetLanguageCode: data.TargetLanguageCode, /* required */
    Text: data.Text, /* required */
  }
};

const translated = await translate.translateText(params.Item.Text).promise();
```

If I console log `params.item.text` it outputs the right thing. But then when i run the `translateText` function I get the error

```
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '0' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '1' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '2' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '3' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '4' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '5' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '6' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '7' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '8' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '9' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '10' found in params
```

Here is the error in cmd:

https://pastebin.com/wLJhTLFR

Full function page:

https://pastebin.com/SmSDF04i

Comment: Maybe give us the output from your console.log on params.Item.Text

Comment: @nubinub It just outputs "Hello World"

Comment: Which library do you use ? I.e where does your translateText method comes from ?

Comment: At the top of the page: `const translate = new AWS.Translate({ apiVersion: '2017-07-01' });`

Comment: @nubinub I have edited the question and put in the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```js
const translated = await translate.translateText(params.Item).promise();
```

See [translateText](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Translate.html#translateText-property) where you see that it expects an object containing `SourceLanguageCode`, `TargetLanguageCode` and `Text`, just like the `Item` key in your `params` variable.

Comment: Is there a way to make `Text` be an object?

Comment: Why? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: My end goal is to use this function to take an item in my dynamodb and translate it to another language, then import it back into the db

Comment: You will have to make multiple calls to `translateText` in this case. You can map over the items returned by your DynamoDB query and call `translateText` followed by `putItem`.

Comment: I have put my entire function in the question above, can you tell me if it looks ok and if im going in the right direction?

Comment: The logic seems fine, don't hesitate to post another question if you encounter other problems with your code.